# Auto suggestion search result error in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, search, autocomplete

I am trying to implement search with auto suggestion in my script but unfortunately I am unable to understand why it is not giving values. I have created two files. One is HTML which has JavaScript functions and some HTML in to and the other one is PHP. Can you please help me to find out what problem is with the code which is not able to display records in the text box?

**File: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function lookup(inputString){
        if (inputString.length==0){
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else{
            $.post("suggestions.php",{
                        queryString: "" + inputString + ""},
                    function(data){
                        $('#suggestions').html(data).show();
                    });
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
<form>
    <input type="text" size="30"  onkeyup="lookup(this.value);">
    <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sandbox Page</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**File: suggestions.php**

```
<p id="searchresults"><?php

$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','RateList');

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])){
    $queryString=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
    if(strlen($queryString)>0){
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM RateList.VoipRoutes" . $queryString);
        if($query){
            while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()){
                echo '<a href="'.$result->name.'">';
                $name=$result->name;
                echo ''.$name.'';
            }
        }
    }
}
?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is malformed. If I type "kittens" into the text box, the SQL query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM RateList.VoipRouteskittens
```